# Reading xml file saved to android internal storage

Tags: xml

I saved an xml file to android internal storage using the following schema and with the following code snippet, but im not sure if i have saved it well, and if someone could give the code to read the text of the nodes named "Banderol" in the xml file that i suppose have saved correctly saved.

Schema:

```
<Banderols>
   <Banderol>Some Value</Banderol>
   <Banderol>Some Other Value</Banderol>
   .
   .
</Banderols>

try{
                DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = 
                DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
                Element rootElement = doc.createElement("Banderols");
                doc.appendChild(rootElement);

                // staff elements
                Element banderol = doc.createElement("Banderol");
                banderol.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(etBanderolNr.getText().toString()));
                rootElement.appendChild(banderol);

                String filename = "savedBanderols.xml";
                FileOutputStream outputStream;

                outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                outputStream.write(doc.toString().getBytes());
                outputStream.close();
            }
            catch (ParserConfigurationException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```